# How to play an encrypted video file (.mpg) with the Vitamio?

Tags: java, android, encryption-symmetric, on-the-fly, vitamio

I work on a project that it must be play an encrypted file with the Aes128(Rijndael) method!
and should not decrypt the file completely at the first  and play it all.
I have to decrypted and play in-the-fly the file at 512 byte blocks.

how can do it with the vitamio; is it possible ?

Attention : It possible with exoplayer but it doesn't supports mpg format.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypted file cannot be played with Vitamio